# ¿como puedo recuperar estos datos en el controlador?

Tags: php, jquery, array, json, codeigniter-4

Estoy usando codeigniter 4 y quiero recorger estos datos que mande por ajax al controlador

esto me imprime pinrt_r()

```
[post] => Array ( 
    [datastring] => date_invoice=2022-11-24&number_invoice=65654654&productos=04&amount=2 
    [select_product_array] => Array ( [0] => 04 [1] => 07 [2] => 10 ) [amount_create_array] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 ) ) ) )
```

este es mi ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert_invoice",
                data:  {
                    datastring: datastring,
                    select_product_array: select_product_array,
                    amount_create_array: amount_create_array
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);  
                    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
                    // do what ever you want with the server response
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('error handling here');
                }
            });
```

controller

```
public function insert_invoice(){
    $session = session();
    $id_user   = $session->get('user_id');
    $fechaActual = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    $accountModel = new AccountModel();
    $request = \Config\Services::request();
    print_r($request);
    //var_dump($request->getPost(json_decode($datastring)));
   
    
}
```

Comment: ese codigo esta comentado y se imprime antes el print_r()

Comment: Ok, bueno, entonces ¿que problema tienes en usar `$request['post']['datastring']` o `$request['post']['select_product_array']` o `$request['post']['amount_create_array']` para acceder a esos datos?  Segun el `print_r` el `$request` es un simple array que contiene una clave denominada `post` que a su vez contiene otro array con esas tres claves... ¿o no estoy entendiendo lo que quieres hacer ahora tampoco?

Comment: Asi es, pero no logro imprimir los datos y tambien lo intente como tu mencionas. esto me arrojo cuando lo intente como dices "Cannot use object of type CodeIgniter\\HTTP\\IncomingRequest as array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según me parece entender quieres hacer dos cosas:

1. Recoger los datos enviados por POST, lo cual parece que en CI4 y según [esta documentación](https://blog.trescomatres.com/2021/04/codeigniter-4-tratar-parametros-post/) se podría hacer así:

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();
$datastring = $request->getPost('datastring');
$select_product_array = $request->getPost('select_product_array');
$amount_create_array = $request->getPost('amount_create_array');
```

2. Y después me parece que quieres descomponer el texto recibido en formato de `query string` contenido en `$datastring` en algo que puedas trabajar. Y para ello puedes probar la funcion [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php) de PHP

```
parse_str($datastring, $datos_recibidos);
```

lo cual convierte el *string* contenido en `$datastring` en variables (si le pasas un segundo parámetro, como yo he puesto `$datos_recibidos`, los pone todos dentro de un *array* en esa variable, para evitar colisiones con variables que ya podrían tener el mismo nombre, por lo tanto, entiendo que si luego haces un:

```
print_r($datos_recibidos);
```

debería aparecerte algo así:

```
Array
( 
    [date_invoice] => "2022-11-24",
    [number_invoice] => "65654654",
    [productos] => "04",
    [amount] => "2" 
)
```

a los cuales, ahora si, podrías acceder con:

```
echo $datos_recibidos['date_invoice'];
etc...
```

Espero que esta vez haya acertado. Ya nos cuentas, gracias.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu respuesta fue perfecta